# Full Calendar datesSet causing infinite loop by using setState

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using a function that call an API according to the current month on the Calendar and fetch some events of that month.
It updates the events in events props of Full Calendar that is causing infinite loop.
How to prevent that?

I want to update the events on changing the months and display the events on the calendar of that particular month.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: datesSet is completely the wrong option for achieving this. Read about your options for setting up an event feed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source